# Only Docx File not upload In PHP 5.4.19

Tags: php

I am using godady server Where PHP version 5.4.19, when I am upload doc or PDF file it's upload properly but when Docx file upload there are some error ....
The www.jobishh.com page isn’t working
www.jobishh.com didn’t send any data.

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

code is..

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $target = "upload/";
    $res_msg = "";
    if ((!empty($_FILES['resume'])) && ($_FILES['resume']['error'] == 0)) {
        $file = $_FILES['resume']['name'];
        $filename = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']);
        $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
        if (($ext == "docx" || $ext == "doc") && ($_FILES['resume']['size'] < 71680000)) {
            if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'], $target . $file))) {
                $res_msg = " and also uploaded your resume.";
            }
        } else {
            $res_msg = "use only doc and docx file.";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="resume">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the size of that docx file ? check that the filesize is under the limit set in PHP.ini. You can find filesize limits with phpinfo(). Because if doc or pdf is successfully uploaded then docx will be surely uploaded.

Comment: My docx file size is 35kb.

Comment: ohk so update your question with your code i have to check it out

Comment: I also checked another hosting server where PHP version 5.4.45, it's work properly. I thing this is a PHP version Error.If you have any Idea about it So please suggest me.